# Adding "unused" VSTS Task Group Parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I know parameters appear when they are used within tasks. The problem is I use them inside publish profiles too (`Visual Studio Build -> MSBuld Arguments -> /p:PublishProfile`) and there is no direct reference to the parameter directly in my task group.

Parts of an example `.pubxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        [...]
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>$(BuildConfiguration)</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        [...]
        <PrecompileBeforePublish>$(PrecompileBeforePublish)</PrecompileBeforePublish>
        [...]
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

`$(BuildConfiguration)` is replaced with the parameter value because it's used inside the Visual Studio Build task (and appears as a parameter in task group), but the `$(ProcompileBeforePublish)` is used only inside the publish profile and the value cannot be set in the task group at all.

I tried adding the parameter to the title of a task, but it does not appear in the parameters list.

I ended up adding a "cmd" and echo'ing the variable, but this seems messy - is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Adding “unused” VSTS Task Group Parameter

I used a method similar to yours when I encountered the same problem as you, I use the `Inline Powershell` task to `Write-Output` the parameter.

Although this method is not very elegant, personally think it is still an effective method.

As we know, Task group parameters are automatically created **based on the variables used in the tasks**. This behavior is **by designed**. So, there is no such option/setting that we could manually add those “unused” parameters into VSTS Task Group Parameter directly.

After a period of investigation, I found a solution that looked more elegant. We create a Task group which not include the “unused” Parameter, then we export the task group and manually edit the json file:

[image]

You can then open the downloaded json file with Visual Studio, Press Ctrl+k Ctrl+D in Visual Studio to format the `json` file, after formatting you can see there is a section named inputs and each of the parameters available there:

```
  "inputs": [
    {
      "aliases": [],
      "options": {},
      "properties": {},
      "name": "BuildConfiguration",
      "label": "BuildConfiguration",
      "defaultValue": "Debug",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "helpMarkDown": "",
      "groupName": ""
    },
```

Now, we could mimic it to add the "unused" parameter `$(PrecompileBeforePublish)`,like:

```
  "inputs": [
    {
      "aliases": [],
      "options": {},
      "properties": {},
      "name": "BuildConfiguration",
      "label": "BuildConfiguration",
      "defaultValue": "Debug",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "helpMarkDown": "",
      "groupName": ""
    },

    {
      "aliases": [],
      "options": {},
      "properties": {},
      "name": "PrecompileBeforePublish",
      "label": "PrecompileBeforePublish",
      "defaultValue": "True",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "helpMarkDown": "",
      "groupName": ""
    },
```

Then you have to import the `json` file in task groups. Unfortunately this will only make a copy of the task group and you would not be able to overwrite existing task group, then we could see the “unused” parameter in the new task group:

[image]

This method looks more elegant, but it doesn't seem to be efficient enough. That is the reason why I said the previous method is not very elegant, personally think it is still an effective method.

If it is important to you, you can submit your request for a feature that we could manually add Task Group Parameter on the [suggest a feature site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21):

[image]

Hope this helps.